# Why this Exception occurs 'o.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: D8322EDA'

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-bluetooth

I'm working with Bluetooth in android.My main goal is to transmit large video file via Bluetooth.
I'm following Bluetooth chat sample for connectivity.
Actually i convert video into byte array and then in onRecieve method convert back to File.
when converting back to file some exception occurs.
I increased the buffer size in connected Thread.

To convert recieved byte[] into Hashmap<String, Byte[]>

```
private Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        Object out = null;
        ObjectInput in = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            out = in.readObject();
            Log.d("bytetodata out", "");
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("bytetodata out", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                // ignore close exception
            }
        }
        Log.d("bytetodata out", "");
        return out;
    }
```

Exception occurs at
 `in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);`

Bluetooth Reciever code

```
case MESSAGE_READ:

                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    onRecieve(readBuf);
```

```
private void onRecieve(byte[] readBuf) {

        HashMap<String, byte[]> receivedMap = (HashMap<String, byte[]>) convertFromBytes(readBuf);
        //Log.d("recieveMAP Size" , String.valueOf(receivedMap.size()));
                if (receivedMap != null && receivedMap.size() == 2) {
                    byte[] filebyte = receivedMap.get("file");
                    byte[] objectbyte = receivedMap.get("object");
                    if (filebyte != null) {
                        File file = new File("storage/emulated/0/Download/name.mp4");
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Mainactivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            try {
                                FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, filebyte);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        } else {
                            //System.out.println("file created: " + file);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "File is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "selected video path = null!");
                    }

                    //System.out.println("file created: " + file);
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "File Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   // Video video = (Video) convertFromBytes(objectbyte);
                }
    }
```

Bluetooth Connectivity code

```
 private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 * 16 ];
            int bytes;
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         *
         * @param buffer The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

***BlutoothConnectivityService.java***

```
package com.example.accessagriculture.Utils;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import com.example.accessagriculture.Views.Fragments.BTListFragment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * This class does all the work for setting up and managing Bluetooth
 * connections with other devices. It has a thread that listens for
 * incoming connections, a thread for connecting with a device, and a
 * thread for performing data transmissions when connected.
 */
public class BTConnectService {

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChat";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BTConnectService(Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     *
     * @param state An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     *
     * @param device The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }
        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     *
     * @param socket The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BTListFragment.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BTListFragment.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        //setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        /*Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       // bundle.putString(BTListFragment.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);*/
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BTConnectService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            setName("ConnectThread");
            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BTConnectService.this.start();
                return;
            }
            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BTConnectService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         *
         * @param buffer The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
               mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListFragment.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                       .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your codes seem to be incomplete. ObjectInputStream requires objects written by ObjectOutputStream. I don't see how you "create" the readBuf and how the readBuf was created. The starting hex codes of an ObjectStream is ACDE.... but your hex codes look weird.

Comment: readBuf is actually the bytes received from the sender side.

Comment: @Joe actually I myself very much confused. after two weeks I'm starting this task again. As to transfer large video files within my app. There are two items to be sent, one is the Video model and the second is the Video file. Now I'm doing this by using a simple Bluetooth chat sample to communicate between devices and for file sharing, convert the whole hashmap to byte array then split it and send data chunks one by one, and on the receiver side, receives all chunks and merge them to create a byte array and then from this, convert it into a hashmap and further...

Comment: HashMap is itself a serializable object. See the codes below and you may know how to create and write (or send) an objec like HashMao

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `readObject()` correctly? What do you think this method does? You probably mean `read(byte[],int,int)` or even `readFully()` if you're lucky enough thus don't get `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

The coding frame with ObjectOutputStream. On the sender site

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
...
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bao);
oos.writeObject(hm);
Socket.getOutputStream().write(bao.toByteArray()); // send the 
...
```

on the receiver site

```
private Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
  ... // your codes
}
```

I'm sorry. I missed to read that you send the bytes in chunks. But, normally the sending takes over the sending package (chunked or not) and the receiving task is responsible for the assembling the chunks. Since you work explicitly with ChunkOutputStream and ChunkInputStream

Comment: Still same error:W/System.err: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FD0875E7

Comment: Pls. provide the codes how you send the package. And on the receive site you should read the entire data into a ByteArrayOutputStream, then load them in ByteArrayInputStream(bao.toByteArray()) before you read them as object in ObjectInputStream().